# How to create and publish a brew package on Ubuntu to ensure that everybody could use it?

Tags: package-management

I have several open source project and I am not a great fan of MacOSX, but I would like to  package these project binaries into brew so that MacOSx users can install the package using brew as well. I read multiple documents, but I do not want to spend a lot of time figuring this out as like I said prefer Ubuntu.

Please add a step by step plan that describes how one creates and publishes a brew package on Ubuntu. The following two projects contain a Darwin binary that could be transformed into a brew package:

- https://github.com/030/n3dr
- https://github.com/030/informado

Comment: I had the same problem, however I went a different route , and used the nix package manager. If you willing to try something new perhaps nix may have some answers if you are not entirely dependant on brew. https://nixos.org

Comment: Both of those already have Snap packages, which makes installing upon Ubuntu two super-easy steps: 1) Ignore Brew instructions. 2) Install the Snap packages instead. Haywiring Brew to work with Ubuntu can be done, but not easily, simply, and safely. In a year or two, the users will be banging their head trying to update or remove the Brew packages. Brew is incompatible with apt and with Snaps, which is a great way to confuse and frustrate users.